# Get ctx.ListData inside Calendars

Tags: javascript, list-view, ctx

I want to retrieve some data about each item in a Calendar, but I can't find `ctx.ListData` inside Calendar view.

Is this a bug in SharePoint?

Comment: that Calendar is a strange beast. You can not apply CSR to it either.

Comment: Calendar view only is strange! Other views are okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea how to term it properly but I suppose that the way Microsoft has offered it to us.

Another thing we can not apply **CSR** for calendar view also. In any other view, we can apply **CSR** and get items using `ctx.ListData.Row`.

So if it is your must requirement, then now consider **REST** or **JSOM** to get all items. For REST API, following is the end-point.

```
"/_api/lists/getbytitle('Name of the calendar list')/items"
```